# Draw Diagram with Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm trying to draw the following figure with Tikz. I looked to many answers and examples in tex.StackExchange and texample.net. It took me a lot of time to get it similar to the original figure, I'm looking for a more efficient and professional way to draw this figure any help I will appreciate.

this is the original figure:
[image: Original figure]

this is my code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, positioning,shadows, shapes}

\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{bcc9cf}
\definecolor{mygrey}{HTML}{d8dfe2}
\definecolor{mywhite}{HTML}{ffffff}

\tikzset{
    RoundedRect/.style={draw, very thick, minimum width=8em, minimum height=8ex, inner ysep=2mm, outer sep=1pt, execute at end node=\vphantom{g},font=\Huge,drop shadow, rounded corners},
    SignalToEast/.style={RoundedRect, inner xsep=-2pt,signal, signal to= east},
    SignalToWest/.style={RoundedRect, inner xsep=-2pt,signal, signal to= west},     
    TextBox/.style={font=\scriptsize\bfseries,  align=center,text width= 2cm},
    smallRect/.style={very thick,draw,rectangle,blue},
    smallElli/.style={very thick,draw,ellipse,red}
}   

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 10mm and 20mm]
    \node (1) [SignalToEast,fill=myblue] {1};
    \node (2) [RoundedRect,fill=mygrey,above right=of 1] {2};
    \node (3) [RoundedRect,fill=mygrey,below right=of 1] {3};
    \node (4) [SignalToWest,fill=myblue,below right=of 2] {4};
    \node (5) [left=2cm of 1] {};
    \node (6) [right=3.5cm of 4] {};            
    \node (7) [TextBox,below =1.5cm of 1.south west] {Description of this node};
    \node (8) [TextBox,below=.5cm of 4.south east] {Description of this node};
        
    % Some auxiliary coordinates for nodNam13 arrows 
    \node (coordNam1) [below=.1mm of 5.south] {};
    
    \node (aux1) [smallRect,right=15mm of coordNam1,inner sep=1.5pt] {7};
    \node (aux2) [smallRect,right=11mm of coordNam1,inner sep=1.5pt] {8};
    \node (aux3) [smallElli,right=6mm of coordNam1,inner sep=1pt] {7};
    \node (aux3) [right=1mm of coordNam1,inner sep=1pt] {$\ldots$};
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \node (coord1) [right=of 4.10] {};
    
    \node (COORD1) [right=.5cm of coord1,inner sep=1pt,blue,yshift=1mm] {$\mathcal{F(\omega}^x_1)$};
    \node (COORD2) [right=-.5cm of coord1,inner sep=1pt,blue,yshift=1mm] {$\mathcal{F(\omega}^y_1)$};
    \node (COORD3) [right=-1.5cm of coord1,inner sep=1pt,red,yshift=1mm] {$\mathcal{F(\omega}^x_2)$};
    \node (COORD4) [right=-2cm of coord1,inner sep=1pt,yshift=.5mm] {$\ldots$};
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \node (3coord1) [left=0mm of 3.north west,inner sep=0pt] {};
        
    \node (3COORD1) [smallElli,left=4mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1pt] {4};
    \node (3COORD2) [smallElli,left=8mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1pt] {5};
    \node (3COORD3) [smallElli,left=12mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1pt] {6};
    \node (3COORD4) [left=16mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1pt] {$\mathcal{\omega}^y_4$};
    
    \node (3COORD1) [smallRect,left=4mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1.5pt,yshift=-6mm] {4};
    \node (3COORD2) [smallRect,left=8mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1.5pt,yshift=-6mm] {5};
    \node (3COORD3) [smallRect,left=12mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1.5pt,yshift=-6mm] {6};
    \node (3COORD4) [left=16mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1pt,yshift=-6mm] {$\mathcal{\omega}^y_4$};
    
    \node (3COORD1) [smallElli,left=1mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1pt,yshift=-13mm] {2};
    \node (3COORD2) [smallElli,left=5mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1pt,yshift=-13mm] {3};
    \node (3COORD3) [smallElli,left=9mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1pt,yshift=-13mm] {4};
    \node (3COORD4) [left=13mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1pt,yshift=-13mm] {$\mathcal{\omega}^y_2$};
    
    \node (3COORD1) [smallRect,left=1mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1.5pt,yshift=-18mm] {2};
    \node (3COORD2) [smallRect,left=5mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1.5pt,yshift=-18mm] {3};
    \node (3COORD3) [smallRect,left=9mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1.5pt,yshift=-18mm] {4};
    \node (3COORD4) [left=13mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1pt,yshift=-18mm] {$\mathcal{\omega}^x_2$};
    
    %******************************************************************************
    \node (below4) [below= 1mm of 4] { };
    \node (FW1) [left=2mm of below4,inner sep=.5pt] {$\mathcal{F(\omega}^x_2)$};
    
    \node (FW2) [left=6mm of below4,inner sep=.5pt,yshift=-5mm] {$\mathcal{F(\omega}^y_2)$};
    
    \node (FW3) [left=11mm of below4,inner sep=.5pt,yshift=-9mm] {$\mathcal{F(\omega}^x_4)$};
    
    \node (FW4) [left=16mm of below4,inner sep=.5pt,yshift=-14mm] {$\mathcal{F(\omega}^y_4)$};
    %******************************************************************************
    
    \draw[circle,below=2mm of coordNam1] (5.east |- 1.west);
    \draw[-latex,very thick] (1) -- (2);
    \draw[-Stealth,very thick] (1) -- (3);
    \draw[-latex,very thick] (3) -- (4);
    \draw[-latex,very thick] (2) -- (4);
    \draw[-latex,very thick] (5) -- (1);
    \draw[-latex,very thick] (4) -- (6);
    \draw[dash dot,very thick] (8) -- (4.text);
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \node (darect) [draw=blue, very thick, minimum width=5.5em, minimum height=8ex, inner ysep=2mm, outer sep=1pt,below =3mm of 1.center,dashed,rounded corners] {};
    
    \node (x1) [smallRect,below=3.5mm of 1.south east,xshift=-5mm,fill=mywhite,inner sep=1.5pt] {4};
    \node (x2) [smallRect,below=3.5mm of 1.south,fill=mywhite,inner sep=1.5pt] {5};
    \node (x3) [smallRect,below=3.5mm of 1.south west,xshift=5mm,fill=mywhite,inner sep=1.5pt] {6};
    
    \node (xx1) [smallElli,below=-2mm of 1.south east,xshift=-5mm,fill=mywhite,inner sep=1pt] {4};
    \node (xx2) [smallElli,below=-2mm of 1.south,fill=mywhite,inner sep=1pt] {5};
    \node (xx3) [smallElli,below=-2mm of 1.south west,xshift=5mm,fill=mywhite,inner sep=1pt] {6};
    
    \draw[dash dot,very thick] (7) -- (darect);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm looking for a technique to position and connect nodes without trying many times.
In my code, I changed the position of nodes with mm until I put it in the proper location.  Is there a method to do it without trying different values?

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx.

Comment: What you did is already of good quality. You may want to look for `chains` to simplify your red and blue labels. And you should use the same arrow tip everywhere. If you want to be more precise with your arrows, you can try this: `\draw[-latex,very thick] (1) -- (2.west);` and create an arrow style with `shorten` to give space between your arrows and your nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a very good initial effort, I just have some small improvements to your MWE.

1. I have noticed that you use too many nodes. I have grouped many of them by defining new commands `\smallElli` and `\smallRect`.
2. I have replaced `\mathcal{\omega}` with `\omega` (they give the same result).
3. I have introduced a command `\myF` for `\mathcal{F}`
4. I have put the text along the arrow from nodes 3 to 4 using nodes along the draw operation.

Hope this helps!

```tex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, positioning,shadows, shapes}

\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{bcc9cf}
\definecolor{mygrey}{HTML}{d8dfe2}
\definecolor{mywhite}{HTML}{ffffff}

\tikzset{
    RoundedRect/.style={draw, very thick, minimum width=8em, minimum height=8ex, inner ysep=2mm, outer sep=1pt, execute at end node=\vphantom{g},font=\Huge,drop shadow, rounded corners},
    SignalToEast/.style={RoundedRect, inner xsep=-2pt,signal, signal to= east},
    SignalToWest/.style={RoundedRect, inner xsep=-2pt,signal, signal to= west},     
    TextBox/.style={font=\scriptsize\bfseries,  align=center,text width= 2cm},
    smallRect/.style={very thick,draw,rectangle,blue},
    smallElli/.style={very thick,draw,ellipse,red}
}

\newcommand{\smallElli}[1]{\tikz{\node[ellipse,draw=red,fill=white,solid,very thick,inner sep=1pt]{{\color{red}#1}};}}
\newcommand{\smallRect}[1]{\tikz{\node[rectangle,draw=blue,fill=white,solid,very thick,inner sep=2pt,rounded corners=0pt]{{\color{blue}#1}};}}
\newcommand{\myF}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{F}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 10mm and 20mm]
        \node (1) [SignalToEast,fill=myblue] {1};
        \node (2) [RoundedRect,fill=mygrey,above right=of 1] {2};
        \node (3) [RoundedRect,fill=mygrey,below right=of 1] {3};
        \node (4) [SignalToWest,fill=myblue,below right=of 2] {4};
        \node (5) [left=2cm of 1] {};
        \node (6) [right=3.5cm of 4] {};            
        \node (7) [TextBox,below =1.5cm of 1.south west] {Description of this node};
        \node (8) [TextBox,below=.5cm of 4.south east] {Description of this node};
        
        % Some auxiliary coordinates for nodNam13 arrows 
        \node (coordNam1) [below=.1mm of 5.south] {};
        
%        \node (aux1) [smallRect,right=15mm of coordNam1,inner sep=1.5pt] {7};
%        \node (aux2) [smallRect,right=11mm of coordNam1,inner sep=1.5pt] {8};
%        \node (aux3) [smallElli,right=6mm of coordNam1,inner sep=1pt] {7};
%        \node (aux3) [right=1mm of coordNam1,inner sep=1pt] {$\ldots$};
        \node [below=1pt of 5,anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt, baseline=0pt] {$\ldots$ \smallElli{7} \smallRect{8} \smallRect{7}};
        %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%        \node (coord1) [right=of 4.10] {};
%        
%        \node (COORD1) [right=.5cm of coord1,inner sep=1pt,blue,yshift=1mm] {$\mathcal{F(\omega}^x_1)$};
%        \node (COORD2) [right=-.5cm of coord1,inner sep=1pt,blue,yshift=1mm] {$\mathcal{F(\omega}^y_1)$};
%        \node (COORD3) [right=-1.5cm of coord1,inner sep=1pt,red,yshift=1mm] {$\mathcal{F(\omega}^x_2)$};
%        \node (COORD4) [right=-2cm of coord1,inner sep=1pt,yshift=.5mm] {$\ldots$};
        \node [above right = 1pt and 1pt of 4.east] {$\ldots {\color{red} \myF(\omega_2^x)} {\color{blue} \myF(\omega_1^y) \myF(\omega_1^x)}$};
        %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%        \node (3coord1) [left=0mm of 3.north west,inner sep=0pt, anchor=south west] {};
        
%        \node (3COORD1) [smallElli,left=4mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1pt] {4};
%        \node (3COORD2) [smallElli,left=8mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1pt] {5};
%        \node (3COORD3) [smallElli,left=12mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1pt] {6};
%        \node (3COORD4) [left=16mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1pt] {$\mathcal{\omega}^y_4$};
        
%        \node (3COORD1) [smallRect,left=4mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1.5pt,yshift=-6mm] {4};
%        \node (3COORD2) [smallRect,left=8mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1.5pt,yshift=-6mm] {5};
%        \node (3COORD3) [smallRect,left=12mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1.5pt,yshift=-6mm] {6};
%        \node (3COORD4) [left=16mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1pt,yshift=-6mm] {$\mathcal{\omega}^y_4$};
        \node [below left = 1.25em and 3em of 3.west,anchor=south east,align=center,inner sep=0pt] {$\omega_4^y$ \smallElli{6} \smallElli{5} \smallElli{4}\\$\omega_4^x$ \smallRect{6} \smallRect{5} \smallRect{4}};
        
%        \node (3COORD1) [smallElli,left=1mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1pt,yshift=-13mm] {2};
%        \node (3COORD2) [smallElli,left=5mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1pt,yshift=-13mm] {3};
%        \node (3COORD3) [smallElli,left=9mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1pt,yshift=-13mm] {4};
%        \node (3COORD4) [left=13mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1pt,yshift=-13mm] {$\mathcal{\omega}^y_2$};
        
%        \node (3COORD1) [smallRect,left=1mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1.5pt,yshift=-18mm] {2};
%        \node (3COORD2) [smallRect,left=5mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1.5pt,yshift=-18mm] {3};
%        \node (3COORD3) [smallRect,left=9mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1.5pt,yshift=-18mm] {4};
%        \node (3COORD4) [left=13mm of 3coord1,inner sep=1pt,yshift=-18mm] {$\mathcal{\omega}^x_2$};

        \node [below left = 1em and 0.25em of 3.west,anchor=north east,align=center] {$\omega_2^y$ \smallElli{4} \smallElli{3} \smallElli{2}\\$\omega_2^x$ \smallRect{4} \smallRect{3} \smallRect{2}};
        
        %******************************************************************************
%        \node (below4) [below= 1mm of 4] { };
%        \node (FW1) [left=2mm of below4,inner sep=.5pt] {$\mathcal{F(\omega}^x_2)$};
%        
%        \node (FW2) [left=6mm of below4,inner sep=.5pt,yshift=-5mm] {$\mathcal{F(\omega}^y_2)$};
%        
%        \node (FW3) [left=11mm of below4,inner sep=.5pt,yshift=-9mm] {$\mathcal{F(\omega}^x_4)$};
%        
%        \node (FW4) [left=16mm of below4,inner sep=.5pt,yshift=-14mm] {$\mathcal{F(\omega}^y_4)$};
        %******************************************************************************
        
        \tikzstyle{temp} = [below=1em, inner sep=0pt, anchor=north west]
        \draw[circle,below=2mm of coordNam1] (5.east |- 1.west);
        \draw[-latex,very thick] (1) -- (2);
        \draw[-Stealth,very thick] (1) -- (3);
        \draw[-latex,very thick] (3) -- node [pos=0.1, temp] {$\myF(\omega_4^y)$} node [pos=0.4, temp] {$\myF(\omega_4^x)$} node [pos=0.7, temp] {$\myF(\omega_2^y)$} node [pos=1, temp] {$\myF(\omega_2^x)$} (4);
        \draw[-latex,very thick] (2) -- (4);
        \draw[-latex,very thick] (5) -- (1);
        \draw[-latex,very thick] (4) -- (6);
        \draw[dash dot,very thick] (8) -- (4.text);
        %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \node (darect) [rectangle, draw=blue, dashed, rounded corners, very thick, below = 3mm of 1.center, align=center] {\smallElli{6} \smallElli{5} \smallElli{4}\\ \smallRect{6} \smallRect{5} \smallRect{4}};
        
%        \node (x1) [smallRect,below=3.5mm of 1.south east,xshift=-5mm,fill=mywhite,inner sep=1.5pt] {4};
%        \node (x2) [smallRect,below=3.5mm of 1.south,fill=mywhite,inner sep=1.5pt] {5};
%        \node (x3) [smallRect,below=3.5mm of 1.south west,xshift=5mm,fill=mywhite,inner sep=1.5pt] {6};
%        
%        \node (xx1) [smallElli,below=-2mm of 1.south east,xshift=-5mm,fill=mywhite,inner sep=1pt] {4};
%        \node (xx2) [smallElli,below=-2mm of 1.south,fill=mywhite,inner sep=1pt] {5};
%        \node (xx3) [smallElli,below=-2mm of 1.south west,xshift=5mm,fill=mywhite,inner sep=1pt] {6};
        
        \draw[dash dot,very thick] (7) -- (darect);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

### Edit

Using the `chains` library as @SebGlav suggested might be furthermore efficient. I am not proficient with that.